# Not able to see website on custom domain in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I am trying to show a website on the custom domain using firebase, but not able to see. I tried to check all the errors but had no luck. Also to troubleshoot I had created a new react app and deployed and redirected that to the custom domain but the error shows the same as in the below screenshot.

Please will any experts let me know how can I configure the firebase app to show on the custom domain.

Please see the error below:

[image]

The website is perfectly running on the firebase default domain.

[image]

Comment: If "the website is perfectly running on the firebase default domain" the problem is not at the level of "standard" Firebase hosting config but at the level of custom domain config. Have you double checked that the config is fully implemented? Maybe you can share the screen shots of the custom domain config popup.

Comment: Hi, @RenaudTarnec Thanks for the help, will surely have a look at this and post a reply ASAP.  But just to make it more clear could you please let me know what steps to consider when doing the config for custom domain? Should I do it in react app or on the C-panel of custom domain. 

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing to do at the level of the app. You need to follow the instructions found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) in the doc, using the wizard for connecting a custom domain from your project's Hosting page,

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, Thanks for the help, I tried all the steps as shown in the doc, but no luck, also as you have asked for the screenshot of the custom domain I have updated my original questions with the image. Please let me know if this can give us any hint. Thanka a million

Comment: The screenshot you've added is not from the Firebase Console.It's there that you need to check the config is complete.

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec Thanks a million again, the steps did help me with the solution I was looking for, I recreated the whole thing and started from blank with a new domain name and it did work for me. However, the problem definitely was with domain config and A records, which I guess my manager did not notice. But thanks for the help again.

Comment: Glad I could help you. I will create an answer then.